# Convert Nested set array To json parent-children using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested, hierarchical-data

i have an array in nested set model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model, And i need convert the array to json parent-children with infinite levels.

Array example:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "cat 2"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "url"
    ["class_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "value2"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "128"
    ["lft"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["rgt"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "sub 1"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "url"
    ["class_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "value1"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "129"
    ["lft"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["rgt"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "cat 1"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "url"
    ["class_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "value1"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "130"
    ["lft"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["rgt"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(8) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "sub 2"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "url"
    ["class_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "value2"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "131"
    ["lft"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["rgt"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(8) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "sub 3"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "url"
    ["class_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "value3"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "132"
    ["lft"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["rgt"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(8) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "item"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "url"
    ["class_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "value1"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "133"
    ["lft"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["rgt"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

json example:

```
[{"name":"Cat 1","value":"value1","children":[{"name":"sub 2", "value":"value2","children":[{"name":"sub 3", "value":"value 3"}]}]}, {"name":"Cat 2","value":"value 2","children":[{"name":"sub 1", "value":"value1"}]},{"name":"item","value":"value1"}]
```

can someone help me create a function to do the Convert?

Comment: i see depth, but don't understand parent-child link. Where it?

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` should be the answer here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: but json_encode dont convert hierarchical-data, only array to json, i want convert nested set to parent-children, like example

Comment: But this array does not map to JSON example you provided. Write a function that will convert array into structure you want (array of objects ) and then json_encode this structure.